# How to configure the Json serializer, to allow Circular References in Azure Functions (V2)?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Suppose, I have a object that has a sub property that references itself.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
}
```

When I try to return it,

```
var pp = new Person();
pp.Name = "TONY";
pp.Children.Add(new Person()
{
     Parent = pp,
     Name = "ESTHER"
});

return new JsonResult(pp);
```

it comes truncated, some Exception happens while serializing it.

```
{"parent":null,"name":"TONY","children":[{
```

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents at line 1 column 43 of the JSON data

On ASP Net we could do this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;     
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

**How can I configure Azure Function Json Serializer, to allow it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the overloaded methods, I found:

[image: overloads]

then I used it with this code:

```
var serializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};

return new JsonResult(p, serializerSettings);
```

And it worked.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Parent": null,
  "Name": "TONY",
  "Children": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "Parent": {
          "$ref": "1"
        },
        "Name": "ESTHER",
        "Children": {
          "$id": "4",
          "$values": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get to config using:

```
var config = req.GetConfiguration();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

The only downside is that you need to create on each function but you could add a custom attribute to make that easier.

Comment: which type has GetConfiguration?